# JPA Pagination on calculated projection

Tags: hibernate, jpa, pagination

I am trying to select some calculated data via JPA. The query looks something like this (example is quite simplified):

```
@Query(value = """
SELECT 
  a.field1 as f1,
  SUM(some clause using joined table) as f2,
  SUM(some other clause using joined table) as f3
FROM EntityA a
  LEFT JOIN EntityB b ON a.field1 = b.field1
WHERE a.field2 = :field2
""")
Page<ProjectionEntity> getSomeCalculatedData(String field2, Pageable pageable);
```

The query is working well without Pageable param. When I add pagination, the result query contains `order by a.f2`, which is not present, as `EntityA` does not contain the field `f2`.

Is there a way how to build Entity structure & projection in a way, that the query works?

Comment: First, you should have an ordering on results used for pagination. Database do not guarantee the same order of results when executing a query over and over, so while page sizes will be what is expected, you might see the same results show up in a few of them, or not see some results at all. I would guess, based on f2 being calculated, that Spring's projection mechanisms are adding it to your query which should be a bug. Try adding your own ordering to see if it stops.

Comment: Pageable is paging & ordering mechanism (as you wrote, when you are paging the results, you have to order it to have correct results). The issue is, that order field calculated from Pageable is translated to entity field as described in question.

Comment: Seems like you already know and are putting something into your pageable object to have spring try to modify the query to "order by a.f2". Spring is not JPA/Hibernate that you've tagged your question with, and it is Spring (presumably) incorrectly determining how that pageable object should modify your query beyond just adding a limit/offset value to it, just as it is doing with the projection. You should add that to your question, and a potential workaround I've suggested is to add ordering to the query definition, not try to modify it through the pageable when using calculated fields.

Answer (score 0):

[Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) is what you are looking for.

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(EntityA.class)
public interface ProjectionEntity {
    String getField1();
    @Mapping("SUM(EntityB[field1 = VIEW(field1)].amount)")
    BigDecimal getF2();
    @Mapping("SUM(EntityB[field1 = VIEW(field1)].tax)")
    BigDecimal getF3();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`ProjectionEntity a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, ProjectionEntity.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<ProjectionEntity> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!